# Relationship between memory cell and time step in LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, timestep

i'm studying LSTM model.

Does one memory cell of hidden layer in LSTM correspond to one timestep?

example code) model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape = (4, 1)))

When implementing LSTMs in Keras, can set the number of memory cells, as in the example code, regardless of the time step. In the example it is 128.

but, A typical LSTM image is shown to correspond 1: 1 with the number of time steps and the number of memory cells. What is the correct answer?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miOyW.png)

Answer (score 1):

as I understand *timestep* is a length of Sequence per each processing (=Window_Size)... that (dependently on parameter "return_sequences=True/False") will return either multi- or single- output per each step of data processed... like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235563/15893581) explained & showed ...

explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46381877/15893581) seems to be better

concerning *memory cell* - [here](https://csy99.github.io/Blog/2020/08/16/hands-on-15-sequence/) *"A part of a NN that preserves some state across time steps is called a memory cell."* - make me consider memory cell to be, probably, a "container" - each for temporal weights per vars in window series, till update of them during further backpropagation (when [statefull=True](https://fairyonice.github.io/Stateful-LSTM-model-training-in-Keras.html)) --

BETTER TO SEE ONCE - [pic here](https://csy99.github.io/Blog/2020/06/16/tf/) memory cell &   the logics of its work [here](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)

KNOW usage of the whole shape - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40633083/15893581) - time_steps for backpropagation

Answer (score 0):

In LSTM, we supply input in the following manner
[samples,timesteps,features]
samples is for number of training examples you want to feed at a time
timesteps is how many values you want to use
Say you mention timesteps=3
So values at t,t-1 and t-2 are used to predict the data at t+1
features is how many dimensions you want to supply at a time
LSTM has memory cells but I am explaining the code part so as not to confuse you
I hope this helps